# How To Play a Double array(includes the waves)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, audio, wav, audio-player

I have a double array includes the waves and I want to play it. First I tried this code(for just one wave):

```
private void DoPlaySound(double p)
    {
        double[] d=new double[1]{p};
        Complex[] c=(DoubleToComplex(d)).ToArray();

        FourierTransform.DFT(c,FourierTransform.Direction.Forward);

        Stream s = Stream.Null;
        StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(s);
        w.Write(c[0].Re);
        w.Close();
        System.Media.SoundPlayer sndp = new SoundPlayer(s);
        sndp.PlayLooping();
    }
```

but `System.Media.SoundPlayer.PlayLooping()` Needs `Wave Header` and I haven't any header and I don't know how to generate it.

I also tried [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202738/how-to-play-extracted-wave-file-byte-array-in-c) but I don't know how to play wave file using `winmm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use [NAduio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/documentation)